# Is it possible to change the subject of the original mail with php before reaching the inbox?

Tags: php, email, cakephp

i am currently reading the mails from mailserver and i would like to change the subject of the all the mail in the mailserver with appending some character to it and send it to user inbox.

is it possible to do with php, if it so how can i do it?

```
<?php

require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();

?>
```

Comment: @Ootegem do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well PHP cant change a line of a file , but it can overwrite the entire file. You would need to ovwerwrite the file , search the file , I would tipycally do this by using the explode function searching the word 'Subject'  or a preg_match which parses a line starting 'Subject' and replace that value you would tipically store in  '$match[0]' by using the str_replace fnctn.

However if you are running on top of a linux system , and you have a mailserver such as postfix , you could call a Sed&Awk script by calling the 'exec' or 'system' command. Just be aware of the dangers of having this enabled , but with a fair amount of common sense you shouldn't have any trouble.
By the way Sed&Awk's special purpose is to modify files and emails can treated as files.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just do the following when echoing out?:

```
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject') . "You're text appended here.";
```

Or this for prepending:

```
$subject = "You're text prepended here." . $Parser->getHeader('subject');
```